# Using jQuery Themeroller on own Website?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

is it possible to have a own jQuery Themeroller on a website?
For example in the user-settings so users can customize the website-theme?

Comment: As opposed to what? You should simply be able to include a local downloaded copy the script on you page.

Comment: Could you be more specific? (not sure sure you need all those tags)

Comment: PHP would be needed for the server-side magic (saving themes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this tutorial: http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Change-Page-Themes-Dynamically-Using-JQuery-Theme-Roller.aspx.

Comment: Very useful for the beginning, any idea how to use this exactly like the themeroller with creating custom themes?

Comment: No, sorry. My best suggestion would be to copy what jQueryUI has done over to your website and go from there.

Comment: @iceteea did bring up a good point above: you'll need some PHP script that creates the PNG images used (different colours, etc...). That script most likely won't be available online.